# Como faço para ler múltiplos arquivos e salvá-los?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
lista = glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/LOCAIS/*.xlsx')
lista
df = [pd.read_excel(file)  for file in lista]
df
#melhorar
dados = df[12]
dados

Pmed=dados['Pessoas']
def es(Pmed):
    calc=0.611*np.exp((17.27*Pmed)/(Pmed+237.3))
    return calc
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ler múltiplos arquivos que seguem um padrão no nome, tente usar algo semelhante ao seguinte exemplo:

```
import glob 


# Returns a list of names in list files. 
print("Using glob.glob()") 
files = glob.glob('/home/geeks/Desktop/gfg/**/*.txt',  
                   recursive = True) 
for file in files: 
    print(file) 


# It returns an iterator which will  
# be printed simultaneously. 
print("\nUsing glob.iglob()") 
for filename in glob.iglob('/home/geeks/Desktop/gfg/**/*.txt', 
                           recursive = True): 
    print(filename)
```

disponível em: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/